# Template routing using routes in Play 2.0 & scala

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to route directly to a template using the routes file?

I am looking for an entry like this,

```
GET     /template/main/*param           views.html.main(param)
```

or something similar. Currently I am forwarding to an action to fetch the template.

**Edit**: Indicated param as well, so that the requirement is clear.

Comment: In an MVC architecture you need a controller in order to transform data for your view that you present to the user.  If you don't have this requirement then gre is right and you might as well just serve a static HTML file.  Play! apps are created with a pre-configured route to host static content from {play_root}/public to http://yourhost/assets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have scala dynamic templates you need a controller for serve them and call in it a template.render() method, so it renders to html.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly route an URL to a template, then it's not a template but a static HTML file.
You can have it in "/public/..." but, I don't know if it's possible to have it somewhere else.

Otherwise, you can still just have one line of code in the controller:

`def myAction = Action(Ok(views.html.main.render()))`

Comment: I have URL params which will make the html dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Use some other web framework that will suit your needs better. It seems you use Play but dont really want to since you want to do things not intended to be done by Play...

Comment: We're only evaluating Play at the moment and are looking at other options as well.